# DynamicNodeProvider generate not correct url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am new in MvcSiteMapProvider. Unfortunately can not find the answer by myself. 
I use MVC4 and MvcSiteMapProvider
My questions:

1) The link Buy (and Buy->Search) links me to localhost but it has to be localhost/Buy/Search

2) The link Toy/Toy-Details/1 does not belong to "Buy" menu (if I reach this link menu Buy->Search disappears) Thank you in advance.

My Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home"
  controller="Toy"
  action="Index"
  key="Home">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Buy"
  controller="Toy"
  action="Search"
  key="ToyBuy">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Search"
  controller="Toy"
  action="Search"
  key="ToySearch">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Toy Search Result"
    controller="Toy" action="Search-Result"
    key="ToySearchResult">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Toy Details"
      controller="Toy"
      action="Toy-Details"
      key="ToyDetail" dynamicNodeProvider="MyToys.Web.DynamicNodeProviders.ToySearchDynamicNodeProvider,MyToys.Web"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Publish" controller="Toy" action="Publish" description=""/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Published" controller="Toy" action="Published" key="ToyPublished" description="">
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" controller="Toy" action="Edit"
      preservedRouteParameters="id" key="ToyPublishedEdit" visibility="false" description=""/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

and ToySearchDynamicNodeProvider:

```
public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
{
  var rep = new ToyRepository();
  foreach (var Toy in rep.Get())
  {
    DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode();
    dynamicNode.ParentKey = "ToySearchResult";
    dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", Toy.ID);
    yield return dynamicNode;
  }
}
```

by the way, I also rewrite MenuHelperModel.cshtml:

```
<div class="hmenu">
  <ul class="tabs">
    @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
    {
       <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</li>
    }
  </ul>
 </div>
 @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
 {
     if (node.IsInCurrentPath)
     {
       if (node.Children.Any()) 
       {
         <div class="vmenu">
           <ul class="tabs">
              @foreach (var child in node.Children)
              {
                 <li><a href="@child.Url">@child.Description</a></li>
              }
           </ul>
         </div>
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Buy (and Buy->Search)

MvcSiteMapProvider uses the MVC UrlHelper class the same as the rest of the MVC framework to generate the URLs. The way the URL is created is dependent on your route configuration. There are several resources available already to help you configure your MVC routes. Here are a few.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

I can't be any more specific than that because you didn't mention what URL scheme you are trying to generate.

## The link Toy/Toy-Details/1 does not belong to "Buy" menu

The reason it is not listed under the "Buy" node is because your dynamic node provider isn't specifying any nodes with a parent key of "ToyBuy".

In general, you will want to specify the dynamic nodes under their main category. When going to a search feature, you can use a single node. You can use the preservedRouteParameters attribute to specify each of your custom route parameters (search term, for example), which will copy the value from the current request to the node and force it to match the node every time.

Home > Search

Then when navigating to a particular search item from the search page, it would take you to the item page that is listed under the category (ToyBuy in this case).

Home > Buy > Item

For a downloadable demo of using preservedRouteParameters, see [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Rememeber a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).

Also note that Toy-Details won't be in the SiteMap. The node that declares a DynamicNodeProvider is only a template node and all of your DynamicNodes take on its attributes by default.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. It is really helpful. Could you take a look at the send part of the question? I added it as an answer to show the code.